# How To Disable Monitor Power Saving for All Users?

Tags: linux, power, power-management

## Question:

In Linux is there a global configuration that is not KDE/Gnome dependent that will stop external monitors/displays from shutting off?

## Scenario

We have a scenario where monitors / t.v.s, etc are plugged into workstations for guest use.  (Demos, alarm clocks, etc.)

These monitors/t.v.s are connected through HDMI, and also receive HD Audio through the HDMI.

However, because these are demo machines, and also because in some scenarios guest profiles are recreated, (and deleted), for every session -- we need a "system-wide" solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current configuration of the PMS is displayed and changed by the command [xset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xset): for instance,

```
 xset s off             #Disable screen saver blanking
 xset -dpms             #Turn off DPMS
 xset s off -dpms       #Disable DPMS and prevent screen from blanking
```

However, [first](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xset)

> These settings will be reset to default values when you log out.

[second](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling)

> Warning: XScreenSaver and xfce4-power-manager use their own DPMS settings and override xset configuration

and [third](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XScreenSaver)

> XScreenSaver manages screen blanking and display energy saving (DPMS) independently of X itself and overrides it.

So you are better off installing the package `XScreenSaver` for your distro (the capitals above are Ok for Arch Linux, Debian *et al.* call it `xscreensaver`,...). The package is configured  for a single person thru a program called `xscreensaver-demo`, the configuration is saved to a file called `$HOME/.xscreensaver`, but unfortunately manual modifications of the file are discarded. You can modify this by writing your own file called `$HOME/.XResources` which will allow you to turn off DPMS, standby, and suspend. The *Default* `.Xresources` is variously located, depending on distro at `/etc/X11/app-defaults` (Debian), `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults` (Arch) and so on.

Notice that XScreenSaver is started automatically by  Xfce4 and LXDE, for the other Desktops (Gnome and KDE) you will have to do it in a suitable way.